# Repeat Animation A a random number of time, then animation B

Tags: animation

I want to repeatedly animate action A a random number of times (e.g. move a cube 5m back and forth), then start animation B (e.g. rotate the cube 180 degrees).

What is the best/most common approach to do that? I don't know how to plug in a random number into the animation frames.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do that in Blender out of the box. Might have been possible in older versions where we had a game engine in Blender with logic systems. Might be possible to make a script for it thought.

Comment: Thanks for that. From my search it does seem to be uncommon. It looks like people achieve random effects by manually offset multiple animations / characters.